# Store persisted dataset as XML

Tags: sql-server, xml, dataset

I persist ADO.NET DataSets as structured XML files. Now I ran into a situation where my application is no longer allowed to use files in a network. Everything has to be SQL Server based. My question(s) are towards ways to either automatically import those persisted Datasets into SQL Server as `FILETABLE` or into a table with ColumnType XML. However, is there a way to use SQL querying the tables inside the DataSet residing in the `FILETABLE` or in the XML Column?

Comment: "However, is there a way to use SQL querying the tables inside the DataSet residing [...] in the XML-Column?" -- Not SQL but there is [a subset of XQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/xquery-language-reference-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15). But if you have fixed schemas, it might be the better idea to translate that into plain relational tables rather than XML.

Comment: If you are storing XML that doesn't have a fixed schema, then your going to end up having to built your XQuery statements dynamically as well; which will be a nightmare (especially if you have no idea what you're doing). If they don't have fixed definitions, is SQL Server, or even a relational database, really the right choice?

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to use SQL querying the tables inside the DataSet residing in the FILETABLE or in the XML-Column?

Sure. The XML data type has the [.query()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/query-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15), and [.value()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/value-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15) methods which you can use to parse and navigate XML documents stored in SQL Server.

As well as the older [OPENXML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openxml-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) XML parsing and querying capability.

You can read [FileTables with TSQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/access-filetables-with-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), and you can convert to XML on demand if the documents are stored as strings or blobs.